# Additional info for error TF26212: Team Foundation Server could not save your changes

Tags: logging, error-handling

Is there any logging in TFS, which would explain in more detail, what happened?

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ServerRejectedChangesException: TF26212: Team Foundation Server could not save your changes. There may be problems with the work item type definition, or a conflicting work item type definition change may require a refresh on your client. Restart your client applicationand try again, or contact your Team Foundation Server administrator. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: TF237165: Team Foundation could not update the work item because of a validation error on the server. This may happen because the work item type has been modified or destroyed, or you do not have permission to update the work item.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.RetryHandler.HandleSoapException(SoapException se)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.Update(String requestId, XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata)   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SendUpdatePackage(XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, Boolean bulk)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.SaveWorkItems(WorkItem[] workitems, Boolean bulk, SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save()
   at ...
```

I get this error (only sometimes) when I save changes for a WorkItem, with bypass of rules under service account.

Validation succeeds for the change. Is it possible to get detail about validation on server side?

Comment: I have found a nice website about [logging in tfs](http://larzjoakimnilzzon.blogspot.cz/2012/04/tracelogging-configuration-in-team.html)

Comment: I have found out, that it is not possible to add two revisions of workitem with the same time (with bypassed rules I'm able to create revisions in the time between last change and current time, but the time of last change is not allowed as a time for next change:)

Comment: Another reason of the same problem (same stack trace) and the solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981287/how-to-change-workflow-state-of-the-newly-created-tfs-work-item-through-api/20007440#20007440