# How to change workflow state of the newly created TFS work item through API?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm creating a work item migration application from "something" to TFS 2013, and I want to have the TFS work items to be in corresponding workflow states as in source system. For instance, if the source work item is in "Closed" state, I want it to be in "Done" state in TFS.

I have followed advises in [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/10/27/tfsapichangeworkitemcreatedandchangeddatetohistoricdates.aspx), which suggests to set `BypassRules` property of the `WorkItemStore` object to `true` in order to be able to set `CreatedDate` field. I suppose, the same applies to changing the workflow state, as it also requires bypassing rules.

So, I tried the following:

```
// obtain collection and authenticate towards it
var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(_tfsUrl), cred);
collection.Authenticate();

// get the work item store object
var store = new WorkItemStore(collection, WorkItemStoreFlags.BypassRules);

// creating the work item
var workItem = new WorkItem(store.Projects[_tfsProjectName].WorkItemTypes["Product Backlog Item"]);

// setting some standard fields
workItem.Title = "some name";
workItem.Description = "some description";

// validating the work item
if (workItem.Validate().Count > 0)
{
   // throw validation rules violated
}

// saving the work item
workItem.Save();
```

As you can see, this sample doesn't violate any validation rules, and `workItem.Validate().Count` returns `0`. But the call to `workItem.Save()` throws the following exception:

> Additional information: TF26212: Team Foundation Server could not save
>   your changes. There may be problems with the work item type
>   definition. Try again or contact your Team Foundation Server
>   administrator.

I double checked that `BypassRules` is set to `true` right before the call to `Save()` method. Besides, the `workItem.IsValid` is also `true`.

The interesting fact is that if I change the way I obtain the `WorkItemStore` object, from

```
var store = new WorkItemStore(collection, WorkItemStoreFlags.BypassRules);
```

to

```
var store = collection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

it can save without any problem! But in this case I don't know how to set `BypassRules` to `true`. This property is read-only when the `WorkItemStore` object is created, and I get validation errors if I try to set workflow step to something other than "New".

So, my basic question is: **how to create work items in TFS through API and be able to change `State` field in this newly created item?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, folks, as it often happens, the answer is in manual. Let me explain.

The [article I referenced](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/10/27/tfsapichangeworkitemcreatedandchangeddatetohistoricdates.aspx) in my question clearly states:

> You need to be a member of the Project Collection Service Accounts

But it doesn't mention that you can't easily add the user or group to `Project Collection Service Accounts`. If you try to do this via web access, you'll fail - the Add button is simply disabled. Besides, the screen shot is misleading, showing an account as a member of `Project Collection Administrators group`.

By default, the `Project Collection Service Accounts group` contains a single group called `Team Foundation Service Accounts`. And this is the group you should add the account to. This can be done with the help of console application called TFSSecurity.exe:

```
TFSSecurity.exe /g+ "Team Foundation Service Accounts" "Domain\my-service-account" /server:http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs
```

This is explained in detail in [this article](http://www.vosseburcht.com/?p=55), which describes exactly my case with the correct resolution. The TFSSecurity.exe can be found at the following location:
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio \Common7\IDE (e.g C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE)